# AdamOptimizer for tensorflow version 1.4.0 and 1.2.1 giving different results

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I ran a convolutional network based on Andrew Ng's course using tensorflow version 1.2.1 and I got replicable results. (the random number generators have fixed seeds)

However when I upgraded to version 1.4.0 I got a completely different replicable results.

Is tensorflow forward compatible for the model and hyperparameters? I thought it should be.

I couldn't see anything that might explain this in the release notes.

1.2.1
Cost after epoch 0: 1.917929
Cost after epoch 5: 1.506757

1.4.0
Cost after epoch 0 : 1.921332
Cost after epoch 5 : 1.904156

I have uploaded the code to https://github.com/chidperi/convolutional_networks

You can run unit_test.py after you have cloned it to see the behavior using whatever tensorflow version you have.

Comment: Consider bringing up this issue to the [github repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) of tensorflow. You might find more useful responses there.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was a bug which is why I held off but I guess it is no harm. Thanks!

Comment: Is the issue specific to adam or does it also happen with vanilla gradient descent?

Comment: That's a good question. Let me run it normal gradient descent with the different versions.